# Como carregar valor do campo TEXTO do módulo digitado no admin para o frontend?

Tags: magento

Tenho um modulo customizado com um campo: "Digite sua mensagem personalizada".
Quero carregar esse campo num bloco na página do produto aonde consta "In Stock" (ou Em Estoque, em português). Até ai tudo bem, eu poderia simplismente modificar a mensagem do arquivo app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/catalog/product/view/type/availability/default.phtml:

```
<p class="availability in-stock">
   <span class="label"><?php echo $this->helper('catalog')->__('Availability:') ?></span>
   <span class="value"><?php echo $this->helper('catalog')->__('In stock') ?></span>
</p>
```

Aonde eu mudaria o campo dentro do `''`, mas o que eu quero é que essa mudança seja feita pelo meu módulo, e, para isso já tenho o meu *default* na pasta do modulo dentro do *template*, a importação via `LAYOUT.xml`:

```
<reference name="product.info.availability">
    <action method="setTemplate"><template>stockmessages/catalog/product/view/type/availability/default.phtml</template></action>
</reference>
```

Beleza, mas eu tava pesquisando formas de dar *load* desse campo TEXT no meu *frontend*, e o que achei foi algo como:

```
echo $_product->getAttributeText('campo_criado_na_system.xml')
```

Porém não funciona dando erro no `product.php` do core, acredito que a forma de pegar o valor do *text* do campo no ADMIN para carregar no FRONTEND seja de outra forma, alguém pode me ajudar? Obrigado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A resposta era simples , aqui está, consegui corrigir a minha dúvida.

`Mage::getStoreConfig('primeiraopçaonosystemXML/segunda/terceira....')`

Isso faz com que pegue o resultado do valor do seu campo pré-determinado nas configurações do seu módulo e exiba no .Phtml